# Header sqlite3.h does not work in a c program

Tags: sqlite, clion, c11

I am trying to use the sqlite library in a main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"


int main() {

    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion());

    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
CMakeFiles\Database.dir/objects.a(main.c.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/Andrea/Desktop/Database/main.c:7: undefined reference to `sqlite3_libversion'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\Database.dir\build.make:104: Database.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/Database.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101: CMakeFiles/Database.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: Database] Error 2
```

I downloaded the sqlite3.h file from the official website and put it in the same folder of the main.c file.
Here is the CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Database C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(Database main.c sqlite3.h)
```

Please, can you help me modify the CMakeList.txt file so that the code can be compiled?

Comment: You need to add `sqlite3.c` to your project source files, not `sqlite3.h`.

Comment: I changed sqlite3.h with sqlite3.c and now I get even more errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to download the almagation source code from this site: [almagation](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). It has all the c files you need. After decompressing it, you can use it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



//sqlite-...0000\ is the default folder name 
//You should store this folder in the same folder with your c file
#include "sqlite-amalgamation-3420000\sqlite3.c" 
#include "sqlite-amalgamation-3420000\sqlite3.h" 


static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);



int main(int argc , char ** argv){


sqlite3 *db;      //The data base pointer 
char *dbErr = 0;  //Use this to store the errors when using sql_exec()
int rc;           //Store the result of the functions you call     

rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db); //Open  the data base 
    rc = sqlite3_exec(
    db, 
    "INSERT INTO PARTALI  "\
    "VALUES "\
    "(1,'NIKOS',  23, 'NES KAFES', 200 ),    "\
    "(2,'PAVLOS ',  55, 'FRAPES', 100 ),        "\
    "(3,'ANTONIA-MEROPI',  23, 'Nespresso', 123 ),  "\
    "(4,'kira',  12, 'frappes', 444 );  "


    , callback //callback function (using only the name means that you pass the address of the function) 
    , 0        //data
    , &dbErr   //error message address 
);



rc = sqlite3_exec(
    db, 
    "SELECT * FROM PARTALI;       "\
    "       "\
    "       "\
    "       "\
    "       "\
    "       "
    , callback //callback function 
    , 0        //data passed to callback function 
    , &dbErr   //error message address 
);

//You can use this function in order to get messeges from 
//each sql command you execute
fprintf(stderr, "sqlite3_errmsg %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;


}

//Callback function ( it is passed with the name of the function. The name of 
//the function is the address ). 
//data    : data that can be used in the callback function
//arg c   : number of columns 
//argv    : field names 
//colname : column names 
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){

for(
    int i = 0; 
    i<argc; 
    i++
){
  printf(
    "%s = %s\n", 
    azColName[i], 
    argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL"
  );
}

printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps!